# Core Web Api - Error: Action has more than one parameter bound from request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

```
[ApiController]
[Route("test")]
public class AdminController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(CarModel car, int[] customers, int model)
    {
        var item = new Car()
        {
            Name = car.Name,
            Price = car.Price
        };
        repository.Create(item, customers, model)
        return Ok(item);
    }
}
```

Car Class

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public int Price{ get; set; }
```

CarModel

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public int Price{ get; set; }}
```

I can add "customers" and "model" parameters to my "Car" class.
But I don't want to add "customers" and "model" parameters to my "Car" class

How can I solve this problem in other ways.

Error
[image]

Comment: Can you you show your Car class pls? I don't understand what is the problem. Why do you put int[] customers, int model in your input parameters?

Comment: The error message clearly states that only one parameter can be bound from the request body and it also provides alternative that can be followed.

Comment: @Sergey I updated the code. I've attached a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: @Nkosi Can't I invalidate this? Can't pass 2 parameters?

Comment: No you cannot invalidate that. That is how the framework was designed. Are all those parameters expected to come from the request body? Are any coming from the URL?.  Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Answer (score 1):

If you post ALL this input parameters from your request body, you have to create ViewModel:

```
 public class CarViewModel
{
public CarModel car {get; set;} 
public int[] customers {get; set;}
public int model {get; set;}
}
```

But I don't think you need all this properties, you can merge some.

Change your action:

```
public IActionResult Create(CarViewModel model)
//or you can try, I don't know how you call your action
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] CarViewModel model)
```

Replace the model in a view with:

```
@model CarViewModel
```

and fix your view controls data binding